# Kivy - Widgets not refreshing when a data has been added in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, kivy

So here's what I'm doing. I am generating buttons depends on how many data I have in my database, and I have an 'Upload' button which adds data in the database. When I add a data, there should be another button that must be generated.

The screen of where the buttons is generated and the screen of the 'Upload' data is different.

What I did is to call the loadVideos method from the OtherVideos class when I successfully add a data on the Upload screen as you can see below: the OtherVideos().loadVideos

So here's my code:

```
class OtherVideos(BoxLayout):

main = ObjectProperty()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(OtherVideos,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.loadVideos()

def loadVideos(self):
    print("loadingvids")
    self.clear_widgets()
    con = MongoClient()
    db = con.nba
    vids = db.videos.find()

    vidnum = 1
    for filename in vids:
        myid = "vid" + str(vidnum)
        getfilename = filename['filename']

        button = Button(id=myid,
                      text=getfilename,
                      color=[0,0.7,1,1],
                      background_color=[1,0.1,0.1,1],
                      bold=1)
        button.bind(on_release=partial(self.change_Title, getfilename))
        button.bind(on_release=partial(self.change_Vid, getfilename))
        self.add_widget(button)
        vidnum += 1

def change_Title(self, title, *args):
    self.main.change_curr_title(title)

def change_Vid(self, myfilename, *args):
    con = MongoClient()
    db = con.nba
    vids = db.videos.find()

    for filename in vids:
        file = os.path.basename(filename['video_path'])
        if myfilename == filename['filename']:
            MainApp.vid = filename['video_path']
            break

    self.main.change_curr_vid(filename['video_path'])
pass

class UploadScreen(Screen):
file_path = ''
file_name = ''

def browseFile(self):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    self.file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Video files", "*.mp4;*.flv;*.avi;*.mkv"),
                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
    file = os.path.basename(self.file_path)

    self.ids.filePath.text = self.file_path
    self.file_name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

def uploadFile(self):
    if os.path.exists(self.ids.filePath.text):
        con = MongoClient()
        db = con.nba
        videos = db.videos

        videos.insert(
            {
                'video_path': self.ids.filePath.text,
                'filename': self.file_name
            })
        popup = Popup(title='NBA Highlights',
                      content=Label(text='Video has been uploaded successfully.'),
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 300))
        popup.open()
        self.ids.filePath.text = ''
        OtherVideos().loadVideos #<-------- This is not working. There's no error but it doesn't refresh the widgets.
    else:
        popup = Popup(title='NBA Highlights',
                      content=Label(text='Invalid path, make sure your video path is correct.'),
                      size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 300))
        popup.open()

pass
```

in the kivy file:

```
<MainApp>:
....
BoxLayout:
....
    BoxLayout:
    ....some widgets
    BoxLayout:
        OtherVideos:
            ...this is where the buttons are generated...
        BoxLayout:

<UploadScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        ...
        BoxLayout:
             label
             text input
             browse button
             upload button
        BoxLayout:
             back button
```

The whole code is here: http://textuploader.com/52v1q

Hope you guys can help me!

Comment: You forgot brackets.

Comment: Same output when I put brackets

Comment: I can see the method is being called because it prints "loadingvids" in shell but the rest of the code doesn't seem to work?

Comment: is the video actually uploaded into the database at that moment? What is the content of `vids`?

Comment: The path and file name of the video is being saved at the database, videos (vids in python) is the collection

Comment: The loadVideos() method is being called at first when you run the code and its working fine, its just that when I call it again when I added another data, it dont work. It should be like this. (clear widgets -> re-add the widgets (with the newly added data))

Comment: Can you prepare a [mcve]?